# Using boost serialization with armadillo datum::nan value

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, nan, armadillo

I use boost serialization in my C++ / CLI program, and some classes have datamembers that contain some double which are initialized to arma::datum::nan (the "not-a-number" value for armadillo library). I serialize via a boost::archive::text_oarchive. When I try to deserialize via boost::archive::text_iarchive oa, a boost serialization archive exception is launched when it tries to read a arma::datum::nan value. I tried using a binary archive, but it seems other types (std::vector> for instance) are not supported. Is there a way I could tell boost how to serialize and deserialize a arma::datum::nan value ?