# How to serialize armadillo's vector

Tags: c++, c++14, armadillo, boost-serialization

How can I serialize `arma::Col`? Below are a MWE and the error output.

**MWE:**

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "armadillo"

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

struct S
{   
    int i;
    arma::Col<double>::fixed<3> cvector;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) 
    {
        ar& i;
        ar& cvector;
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;

    S s;

    if (world.rank() == 0)
    {
        s.cvector[0] = 2;
        s.cvector[1] = 2;
        world.send(1, 0, s);
    }
    else
    {
        world.recv(0, 0, s);
        std::cout << s.cvector[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << s.cvector[1] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Error output (skipping "required from" stuff):**

`error: ‘class arma::Col<double>::fixed<3ull>’ has no member named ‘serialize’; did you mean ‘set_size’?
         t.serialize(ar, file_version);`

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231895/using-boost-serialization-with-armadillo-datumnan-value) post seems to be related to my question and unfortunately it is unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

The real crux of the issue here is that you want to add a `serialize()` member function to the various Armadillo objects, but that doesn't appear to be possible... except that thanks to a clever use of the preprocessor in Armadillo, it is!

Take a look at `Mat_bones.hpp` and `Col_bones.hpp`... you'll see something like this, inside of the class definitions of `Mat` and `Col`:

```
public:

#ifdef ARMA_EXTRA_COL_PROTO
  #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(ARMA_EXTRA_COL_PROTO)
#endif
```

It made me very happy when I found this, because now I can do something like define a file called `Mat_extra_bones.hpp`:

```
//! Add a serialization operator.
template<typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version);
```

and then `Mat_extra_meat.hpp`:

```
// Add a serialization operator.
template<typename eT>
template<typename Archive>
void Mat<eT>::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /* version */)
{
  using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
  using boost::serialization::make_array;

  const uword old_n_elem = n_elem;

  // This is accurate from Armadillo 3.6.0 onwards.
  // We can't use BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP() because of the access::rw() call.
  ar & make_nvp("n_rows", access::rw(n_rows));
  ar & make_nvp("n_cols", access::rw(n_cols));
  ar & make_nvp("n_elem", access::rw(n_elem));
  ar & make_nvp("vec_state", access::rw(vec_state));

  // mem_state will always be 0 on load, so we don't need to save it.
  if (Archive::is_loading::value)
  {
    // Don't free if local memory is being used.
    if (mem_state == 0 && mem != NULL && old_n_elem > arma_config::mat_prealloc)
    {
      memory::release(access::rw(mem));
    }

    access::rw(mem_state) = 0;

    // We also need to allocate the memory we're using.
    init_cold();
  }

  ar & make_array(access::rwp(mem), n_elem);
}
```

Then, in your program, all you need to do is

```
#define ARMA_EXTRA_MAT_PROTO mat_extra_bones.hpp
#define ARMA_EXTRA_MAT_MEAT mat_extra_meat.hpp
```

and the `serialize()` function will be a member of the `Mat` class.  You can easily adapt this solution for other Armadillo types.

In fact this is exactly what the mlpack library (http://www.mlpack.org/) does, so if you are interested you can take a closer look at the exact solution I implemented there:

https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/tree/master/src/mlpack/core/arma_extend

Comment: I should add, this was written for `Col` not `Col::fixed` like you are using.  So some minor modification may be necessary.

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question... I find your solution very elegant, however I'm having some issues compiling it, in particular I get the error "boost::serialization has not been declared" if I add these files as they are, instead if I include all the necessary headers in Mat_extra_meat.hpp, I get the error /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/integral_constant.hpp:42:15: error: ‘::mpl_’ has not been declared using ::mpl_::bool_;
Do you have any hints on how to compile and link these files?

Comment: Definitely you can't include the headers in `Mat_extra_meat.hpp` because anything in that file is included directly as part of the Mat class.  So, perhaps, before you include `<armadillo>` you need to include `<boost/serialization.hpp>`?

Answer (score 1):

Since arm::Col::fixed doesn't support serialisation itself, you can either write it in your S class, or write a class that wraps it and serialises it.  I'd recommend the 2nd option since it will let you use arm::Col::fixed in anything that you want to serialise without repeating.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote what you suggested in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to @UKMonkey answer I wrote a working example. Actually for this case there is no need to split `serialize` to`save` and `load`.

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
//#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "armadillo"

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

typedef arma::Col<double>::fixed<3> cvector;

//BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(cvector)

namespace boost
{   
    namespace serialization
    {
        /*template<class Archive>
        void save(Archive& ar, const cvector& cv, unsigned int)
        {
            std::cout << "saving" << std::endl;
            ar& cv[0];
            ar& cv[1];
            ar& cv[2];
        }
        template<class Archive>
        void load(Archive& ar, cvector& cv, unsigned int)
        {
            std::cout << "loading" << std::endl;
            ar& cv[0];
            ar& cv[1];
            ar& cv[2];
        }*/      
        template<class Archive>
        inlide void serialize(Archive& ar, cvector& cv, unsigned int)
        {
            ar& cv[0];
            ar& cv[1];
            ar& cv[2];
        }
    }
} 

struct S
{
    int i;
    cvector c;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int) 
    {
        ar& i;
        ar& c;
    }
};

int main()
{
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;

    S s;

    if (world.rank() == 0)
    {
        s.i = 3;
        s.c[0] = 2.;
        s.c[1] = 4.;
        world.send(1, 0, s);
    }
    else
    {
        world.recv(0, 0, s);
        std::cout << s.i << std::endl;
        std::cout << s.c[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << s.c[1] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may wish to avoid putting anything in the boost namespace, unless you plan to put it into boost... it's not likely to cause you a headache, but it could.

When loading to a vector, you may wish to consider that it could be in any state ... (could be any size, could have data etc).

Other than that - looks like it should do the job.

Comment: But `save` and `load` are defined in `boost::serialization`.

Comment: @Shibli : And those are called in such a manner as to use ADL, so they _should_ go in the same namespace as the type they're effecting.